# trigger function on multiple events/input fields and calculate them?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this small functions that trigger the even to calculate the numbers and sum of input fields with class `mad`

```
$(".mad").each(function() {
  $(this).keyup(function() {
  calculateSum();
  });
});
```

However I have two types of input fields I need to calculate `mad` and `mad2`
so I was thinking if something like this would be possible to trigger the calculation on both  `mad` and `mad2` fields?

```
 $(".mad" && ".mad2").each(function() {
      $(this).keyup(function() {
      calculateSum();
      });
    });
```

Comment: Learn about the libraries you use: https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, use this:

```
 $(".mad, .mad2")
```

Your code would become:

```
$(".mad, .mad2").keyup(function() {
   calculateSum();
});
```

jQuery are using CSS selectors, so basically you can do anything that CSS selectors can.
http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: You don't need `each` to add an event for them, I will update my post.

Comment: $(function () {
   //trigger calculate numbers and sum event
   $(".mad",".mad2").each(function() {
    $(this).keyup(function() {
     calculateSum();
    });
            });

Comment: Check it now and try that. That code you sent above is wrong also. It shouldn't be 2 strings... Just `".mad, .mad2"` not `".mad", ".mad2"`

Answer (score 1):

You should go through [`multiple selector`](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/). Try this:

```
$(".mad,.mad2").each(function() {
      $(this).keyup(function() {
      calculateSum();
      });
});
```